# How to extract time using CriteriaBuilder and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have a problem to map PostgreSQL expression below, that extracts hours/minutes/dow, to a CriteriaBuilder expression:

```
select extract(hour from start_time) from meetings where id = 5;
```

`meetings` have `start_time` field in a database that maps into `ZonedDateTime start` Java entity field later. I have tried `CriteriaBuilder.function()`, but I can not realy understand how to map `hour from start_time` expression as one function parameter.

Thanks for a help!

Comment: Exactly what data type is your column `start_time`?

Comment: @basil-bourque timestamp

Comment: Such facts belong in your Question rather than Comments.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` in Postgres (and the SQL standard) maps to `java.time.LocalDateTime` because it lacks the context of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So trying to map that to a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` **does not make sense**. A `ZonedDateTime` represents a date and time-of-day as seen in a particular time zone. You need to apply a particular time zone, the zone intended for your particular meeting entity. That intended zone should be stored as another column in your database. Then to generate a schedule, apply the zone to the `LocalDateTime` to determine a point (ZDT) on timeline.

Comment: @basil-bourque the question is how to map fetching (for example) minutes from `timestamp` using `CriteriaBuilder`'s instruments. I do not care about time zones and other staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `DATE_PART` function to fetch hours count instead:

```
builder.function("DATE_PART", Integer.class, builder.literal("hour"), root.get("start_time"))
```

SQL-request looks similar:

```
select date_part('hour', start_time) from meetings where id = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract/Date_Part will give only the specified [subfield](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) from the timestamp (I assume `ZonedDateTime`  maps to the Postgres data type `timestamp with time zone`). If you want the full time (hh:mi:ss) then rather that an `extract` for each you just cast the column to `time`. So

```
select start::time, ...           -- Postgres exclusive 
OR 
select cast(start to time), ...   --- SQL standard
```

If you do not want seconds then use to_char:

```
select to_char(start, 'hh:mm'), ...
```